# How to call a static method in Kendo Grid column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I use a Kendo grid to show my table fields like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.Admin.Models.MyViewModel>(Model)
    .Name("id")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Filterable(false);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ModelNo).Filterable(false);
```

It works fine but one of the fields is userId , a GUID field and I want to call a static method which returns Username. I've already created this method. The method is

```
 public static string GetUserName(Guid UserId)
        {
            var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var user = (from k in db.Users where k.Id == UserId.ToString() select k).FirstOrDefault();
            if(user != null)
            {
                return user.UserName;
            }
            else
            {
                return "-";
            }

        }
```

So what I need is to call this method in Kendo Grid, something like:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.UserID).Template(@<text>
            <strong>@Tools.GetUserName(c.UserID)</strong>
        </text>);
```

Comment: Why not you create a viewmodel and resolve UserId with the name before returning to kendoGrid. It might not be  great idea to call getusername on every row of data you have.

Comment: I've done that and it works. I actually wondering if there is any way to call a method in Kendo Grid in case of need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      columns.Bound(p => p.Title).Template(@<text>
           <strong>@item.Title</strong>
      </text>);
```

simply generates javascript like this one

```
  columns: [{
    ...
    template: "<strong>#:Title#</strong>"
  }],
```

And `template: "<text><strong>#:Title#</strong></text>"` further processed by [templating engine](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview) in the Kendo UI Framework at client side. Therefore replacing #:Title# to any C# function wouldn't be recognized at browser end.

Comment: Agree with this... @Amir978 You have to consider that whatever you try to do on the C# side, will at the end, be transfored into a gigantic javascript block that will be send with the HTML code of your page... kind of inline scripting... so every time you use the C# extensions,  you're basically using the handicapped version of kendo. Switch to JS and you will be able to experience kendo in GOD mode...